# All custom cell imageViews disappeared after updating to iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I implemented iOS10 in my app. 
My working code to fetch images from the web and displaying them in `TableView` stopped working.

My cells seem to be disappeared:

```
    print(cell.miniImg.isHidden)
    print(cell.miniImg.alpha)
```

Gives me `false` and  `1.0`

I did also try to display a simple image, but the just the imageView won't appear. 
Also I have checked whether I could display a border to the View, but I can't.

Any ideas?

Comment: please make sure that nothing is overlaying it, make minImg RedColor.

Comment: made background blue and cell background red. can't see the imageView, but the textView.